# Configure Route apiResource in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

I have code in my controller:

```
    public function show(Postmeta $sku)
{
    $sql = "select * from wp_posts po
    join wp_postmeta wp on wp.post_id = po.ID and wp.meta_key = '_sku'
    where po.post_type = 'product' and wp.meta_value = ?";

    $prod = DB::select($sql, array($sku));

    return response(['product' => CEOResource::collection($prod),
        'message' => 'Retrived Successfully'], 200);
}
```

My route is:

```
Route::apiResource('productos', ProductosController::class )->parameters([
'productos' => 'sku'])->middleware('auth:api');
```

I call the API:

> http://localhost:8081/sportzone-api/public/api/productos/woo-belt

The result is:

> ```
> "message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `wp_postmeta` where `id` = woo-belt limit 1)",
> ```

```
"exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
```

I don't understand the problem.

Thank you

Comment: That error appears unrelated to the code you have provided. It is informing you that the column `id` doesn't exist on the `wp_postmeta` table in your database.

Comment: But the query works without problems, then the problem could be in Route::apiResource()

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem change my Action:

```
    public function show($producto)
{
    $match = [
        'wp_postmeta.meta_key' => '_sku',
        'wp_posts.post_type' => 'product',
        'wp_postmeta.meta_value' => $producto
    ];
    
    $prod = Postmeta::join("wp_posts","wp_postmeta.post_id","=","wp_posts.ID")
    ->where($match)
    ->get();   
    

    return response(['product' => CEOResource::collection($prod),
        'message' => 'Retrived Successfully'], 200);
}
```

And Change mi route:

```
Route::apiResource('/productos', ProductosController::class);
```

Thank you